# How can I isolate a .exe from its deployment package?

Tags: c++, windows, qml

I'm trying to figure out how to isolate the .exe file for the app I'm building from the .dll files because the directory in which all of these files are located is very large.

I've already tried using iexpress.exe to make an installer for the app, but every time I have I get an error saying that it could not install because some of the .dll files were not found.

Would statically linking the libraries fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by isolate? [windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) has a `--dir` option which will install everything necessary for the application to the given directory.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to link the executable statically? This means the needed symbols are compiled into the .exe and the folder will not be that large. For this you need to have a statically build version of Qt.